# C# simply chart binding

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

The idea is to simply to plot arrD[i] in a chart called chart5 SeriesA. The issue is that nothing is plotted in the windows form. Maybe someone could help. Many thanks.

```
chart5 = new Chart();
Series SeriesA = new Series();           
Dictionary<int, double> value5 = new Dictionary<int, double>();
for (int i = 0; i < monthCount; i++)
{
    value5.Add(i, arrD[i]);
}
SeriesA.XValueMember = "Location";
SeriesA.YValueMembers = "Value";
chart5.DataSource = value5;
chart5.Series.Add("SeriesA");
```

Comment: chart5.DataBind(); ?? maybe?

Comment: no, even if I add chart5.DataBind() it doesn't work ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I simplified the binding (which works well now) as well as the loop for hiding the zero values. But how to print now the modified chart without zero values .. many thanks.

```
chart7.Series["Series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart7.Series["Series3"].Points.DataBindXY(xVal, arrDouble3);

foreach (Series series in chart7.Series)
{
   foreach (DataPoint arrP in series.Points)
   {
       if (arrP.YValues.Length > 0 && (double)arrP.YValues.GetValue(0) == 0)
       { 
            arrP.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;                   
       }
    }
 }

 chart7.Series["Series3"].Points.DataBindXY(xVal, arrP);    ????
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not add the series you created to your chart.
Try this code :

```
Series SeriesA = new Series();
SeriesA.Points.DataBind(arrD, "Location", "Value", "");
chart5.Series.Add(SeriesA);
```

Note that we add `SeriesA` and not `"SeriesA"`